# Get locale Date Time String from GMT time long in JAVA

Tags: java, datetime, gmt

I need help for my project.

My user datebase has time offset with GMT like this object
{userid:"XTGTS12",timezoneoffset:-8} at GMT/UTC -8:00 which is PST locale.
each user in different timezoneOffset around the world.

I need to send out push notification to user telling them the server down time like:
"The server is going to shutdown at {0}"

The Admin pass a GMT time long to me and I need pull all user object, according to the timezoneoffset integer to generate the date and time and whole string to user at their local time.

I am not sure how to implement in Java.

If the Admin pass me a GMT time long, which is 2016-04-01 00:00:00

The final string I should send to user at timezoneOffset -8 is
"The server is going to shutdown at 2016-03-31 16:00:00"

Comment: there is method [`.setTimeZone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29) in `SimpleDateFormat`, and a [`TimeZone.getTimeZone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone%28java.lang.String%29)--these will help you to format a timestamp in particular timezone.

Comment: I think that the best way is to deal with local time in client side (maybe in javascript) and only GMT on server side.

Comment: By the way, for that kind of important message I would append the offset (or name of time zone) to make clear you are displaying the time adjusted to a particular locality.

Answer (score 1):

Here is exactly what you would need to do. But I hope you realize that storing an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), rather than a [time zone ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), means each user will be "stuck" in standard time. That is to say, a user with offset -8 is, as you say, in **PST** even though, on April 1, they *should* be in PDT, or -7 hours from UTC.

So here is an answer using a fixed offset and assuming that `millis` is your "GMT time long". This code uses the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later (see [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)).

```
    Instant inst = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis);
    OffsetDateTime odt = inst.atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofHours(-8));
    DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(f.format(odt));
```

Now, should you realize you actually want to associate a user with a [*time zone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) like [`America/Los_Angeles`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Los_Angeles) or [`PST8PDT`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PST8PDT), you should instead do this:

```
    Instant inst = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis);
    ZonedDateTime zdt = inst.atZone(ZoneId.of("PST8PDT"));
    DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(f.format(zdt));
```